# How to solve a type error while using RAdam optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building a neural network using keras and tensorflow and I get a error at this place

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RAdam(learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = create_model()
```

And I get the following error when I run my code in jupyter notebook,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2358feb9246f> in <module>
      1 # make a shallow neural network
----> 2 model = create_model()
      3 model.summary()

<ipython-input-13-7c6ab8b2130e> in create_model()
     10 
     11   # Compile model
---> 12   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RAdam(learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
     13   return model

~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras_radam\optimizers.py in __init__(self, learning_rate, beta_1, beta_2, epsilon, decay, weight_decay, amsgrad, total_steps, warmup_proportion, min_lr, **kwargs)
     32                  total_steps=0, warmup_proportion=0.1, min_lr=0., **kwargs):
     33         learning_rate = kwargs.pop('learning_rate', learning_rate)
---> 34         super(RAdam, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     35         with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
     36             self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

And these are the imports I have used for my code to run. I think I have most of the codes imported to build a shallow neural network

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras_radam import RAdam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who may be looking for another solution.

`RAdam` is not in `tensorflow.keras.optimizers` and neither in `keras` by default, but in `tensorflow-addons` package, which is a better alternative (IMHO) than the external `keras_radam` library, considerably less prone to errors.

What you are looking for is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/RectifiedAdam

```
#pip install tensorflow-addons
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.RectifiedAdam(lr=1e-3)
```

Comment: This was my first thought, too, but it seems OP has installed the [keras-radam](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam/blob/master/README.md) package (see the error message).

Comment: @desertnaut and Timbus Calin ,my code ran fine after using the changed adam optimizer, thanks mates!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem. It happened when you have `tf. keras` but you load [`keras-radam`](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam) with old `keras`. But this implementation supports both versions of `keras` or `tf. keras`. To use it with the new version, as also mentioned [here](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam#use-tfkeras-or-tf-20), all you need to do as follows:

```
import os 
os.environ['TF_KERAS']='1'
from keras_radam import RAdam
```

The package will [choose](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam/blob/master/keras_radam/selection.py) the `tf. keras` compatible version of `RAdam()`

```
from .backend import TF_KERAS

__all__ = ['RAdam']

if TF_KERAS:
    from .optimizer_v2 import RAdam
else:
    from .optimizers import
```

So, `RAdam()` will be imported from this [script](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam/blob/master/keras_radam/optimizer_v2.py). But there is another issue. In the very latest version of `tf`, the following import has been updated

```
# from 
from tensorflow.python import os, math_ops, state_ops, control_flow_ops

# to 
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops, state_ops, control_flow_ops
```

From this point, you need to modify this import from the source script and it will solve this issue. Just modify the source [script](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-radam/blob/master/keras_radam/optimizer_v2.py) by replacing the above imports.

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
  model.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                optimizer=RAdam(learning_rate), 
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = create_model()
```

Comment: I was about to ask another question as how to increase the accuracy of the model I was creating and your answer came to me at a right time. Thank you so much for your help!